# Why TextEncoder.encode() produces different result from File.arrayBuffer()?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, uint8array

Here's the simple code:

```js
document.querySelector('#upload').addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
  const initialFile = e.target.files[0];
  const arrayBuffer = await initialFile.arrayBuffer();

  const text = await initialFile.text();
  var enc = new TextEncoder();
  const arrayBufferFromText = enc.encode(text).buffer

  // WHY THESE TWO AREN'T THE SAME?
  console.log(arrayBuffer.byteLength)
  console.log(arrayBufferFromText.byteLength);
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload">
```

When uploading a **binary file**, e.g. an image, `arrayBuffer` will be different from `arrayBufferFromText`. That's apparently happening somewhere in the text -> buffer conversion using `TextEncoder`.

Why is this happening and how to get `arrayBufferFromText` the same as `arrayBuffer`?

Comment: `text()` interprets the input as UTF-8. If the input is not actually UTF-8 you will either get an error or some replacement characters (depending on which APIs are used). In other words: treating arbitrary binary data as UTF-8 is not a reliably reversable operation (it *can* be in some cases, but if it's truly binary data that is quite rare). How do you fix this? Don't use `text()` if the input is not known to be text.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Joachim Sauer. Did I understand correctly that `text()` will create an invalid result that can't be converted back to the original binary `File` or buffer?

Comment: Yes, that's extremely likely to happen when trying to interpret binary data as text, and especially when using UTF-8 for that. If you don't know what the data is, then you should always treat it as binary, that's the safe bet.

Comment: Do it the other way round: `await file.text()` should have the same result as `new TextDecoder().decode(await file.arrayBuffer())`. But as Joachim said, text is not a (good, if at all) representation of binary data.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You might want to post that as an answer

Comment: Thank you both for the prompt answers! @JoachimSauer please post your answer, I'll accept it.